# Shouldnt the Padding on the right fill in the empty space so that it cant be occupied by other divs?

Tags: css

Im having a small issue here. I'm trying to have `A` div with `left 25%` and `width 25%`, and another div next to it with `width 25%` and `padding-right 25%` to fill in the last bit so that both divs take up the entire width. For some reason, the padding is not taking up space and one of the 4 divs below is taking up that space. in this fiddle its kinda broken but this is as close of a replica to the problem. The 4 divs are supposed to be on the next line so that I have 2 divs on 1 line with 4 divs under them. In the fiddle, all the 4 divs are on top of each other which is not my problem. My problem is that they are ignoring the Padding and taking up that space. https://jsfiddle.net/bwxbg7tr/4/

[this is the layout I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUSqf.png)

[instead, I'm getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORXll.png)

imagine the above as the div layout.

Comment: Use Flex-box instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is going on in your example, but this is the easiest way to achieve this layout:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.row:first-child {
  margin: 0 25%;
}

.row div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div> 1.1 </div>
  <div> 1.2 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div> 2.1 </div>
  <div> 2.2 </div>
  <div> 2.3 </div>
  <div> 2.4 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i used Flex and it worked nicely, but this is another way also using flex that worked. Thanks for the response @wilhelm-olejnik

Comment: its also more efficient than my way